# Linux/Bash rename folders regex

Tags: linux, bash

i'm trying to automate a process, and for that, I need to strip a part of a foldername.
Folders are named dummy1R1, dummy2R1, dummyLongerR1. 
I need to strip the R1 from the folder names, for a certain parent folder.
I have looked into "rename" but that only works for files, and "find" doesn't show me if I can reuse a grouping in regex.

All help appreciated

Comment: [`prename`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) on my (ubuntu 14.04) system works for directories too...

Comment: using redhat linux, rename on ubuntu is different apparantly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using bash, you can use the variable expansion. Also "mv" does work on Linux to rename a directory.

So

```
for d in *R1
do
    mv $d ${d%%R1}
done
```

For all entries ending in "R1" rename it to the name with the "R1" removed. For more information, look at the bash manual page, the section on "Parameter Expansion"

Comment: awesome, thanks :D
You have a typo though: you use d in your for loop, but i in your reference...

Comment: Many thanks for the heads-up on the typo.